# Running compiled Linux executable on other Linux computers

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, executable, pyinstaller

I've been working on a custom program that allows me to control my other Linux-based computers on my network. I've been using Python and used PyInstaller to compile the code into a Linux executable.
Running the executable on my own computer works just fine and does exactly what it's supposed to. But once I send it over to another computer to test it, I get this error.

```
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIXcUz91/libudev.so.1)
[3716] Failed to execute script RP
```

And the command I used to compile the code with PyInstaller

```
python pyinstaller.py -D -F -n RP -c RP.py
```

Again, the executable runs perfectly on the computer I used to create and compile it, but once I send it over to my other Linux-based computer and execute it, it crashes.

Comment: Did you consider installing Python on the other computers, or using the one already installed (with most Linux distributions), and sending just the Python code?

Comment: I could do that, but I would have to re-write some parts of my code and sending just a one-file executable is simpler. It has a built in function that allows me to update it by sending a new executable and that would need to be replaced with a more complicated way of updating it. Plus it uses a lot of different imports and I would rather not install all of them on each of my computers (my executable will also be loaded onto newly installed Linux distros in my network and I'd like to keep it simple)

Comment: I've actually struggled with this issue before, but never found a solution, so I just stopped working on my program.
It would be easier for me in just about every way if I found a solution for this that still allows me to use my single-file executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have different C system libraries on the two machines. There can sometimes be difficulties when porting a pre-built binary. Either you ensure that you're using a similar environment or you put all dependencies into the binary - this may increase its size significantly. To do the latter you need to use the ´--static´ keyword during compilation. I'm not sure, though, whether this is enough.

EDIT:

Since this is a pure Python project, you should make sure that the used Python version is compatible, i.e., same Python version and also the same Python build (CPython, etc.).

Comment: I'll try it and let you know

Comment: Did you mean '--static' as in a PyInstaller option? Cause PyInstaller doesn't have a '--static' option

Comment: No, I meant ´--static´ when compiling the C/C++ code. I just realized that you're only working with Python. Editing my answer...

Comment: Ahhh. Yeah, I'm just working with Python. This seems to be an issue with one of my imports (which I did not create)

Comment: One machine is running Python 2.7.14 and the other (the one I'm testing my exec on) is running Python 2.7.13. So there is a slight difference in the versions.

Comment: Just checked the CPython versions and there was a bigger difference, which would make sense.
Main PC: GCC 7.2.0
Test PC:  GCC 6.3.0

Comment: How could I update GCC to a specific version? Version 7.2.0 specifically
It's probably a stupid question, but I've never done it before.

Comment: Using your package manager. This might be difficult because most Linux distributions only support a slightly outdated gcc...

Comment: In that case, I see now that it's not going to be as simple as I hoped to get past this. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

use ldd 
if you file is RP
ldd RP 
- looking for dynamice  so libraries used by the executable if you can change the linking of your program to static libraries, may be able to make more portable else you will have to stay on same release of linux to run your program.  You could also package the .so dependencies with your executable,but messy.